# How to connect my Android phone in USB Debugging mode?

Tags: usb, android, samsung, debugging

In windows, I used to connect my phones (Samsung Galaxy S3 I9300 & Samsung Galaxy Note3 N9005) to my PC after installing the USB driver, and  enable USB Debuggng in the phone and debug my applications using the Android Studio. I installed the Android Studio on Ubuntu but I don't know how to install the driver or how to connect my phone in debugging mode. when I connect the phone I can read the phone as a storage.

Answer (score 1):

If you have set enabled USB Debugging in Developers Options on your devices, just connect your phone with PC by USB.

USB Debugging would turn on automatically an you would see an icon in phone's notification bar

Linux doesn't need any additional drivers like Windows.

Comment: But need to set rules to detect the specific vendor.

Comment: (1) I had to use a pure USB-C to USB-C cable to get "USB debugging mode" to show up on my phone then (2) before device would show on my desktop I had to install adb in ubuntu and configure a udev rule specific to my phone: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50977175/431425